# Conditional utility classes using Tailwind and Astro

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, astrojs

I am using [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com) and [Astro](https://astro.build).

I created this menu link component:

```
// MenuItem.astro

---
type Props = {
  title: string;
  path: string;
};

const { title, path } = Astro.props;
const pathname = new URL(Astro.request.url).pathname;
const currentPath = pathname.slice(1);
---

<li>
  <a
    href={path}
    class=`${currentPath === path
? 'text-red'
: 'text-blue'} relative`
    >{title}</a
  >
</li>
```

Is there a way to make this cleaner? To use something different then a `ternary`, using Astro?

Comment: you can use one of the utility packages like classnames, clsx, tw-merge, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `class:list` syntax [docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#classlist)

```html
<li>
  <a
    href={path}
    class:list={
 [
   {
      relative:true,
      'text-red': currentPath === path,
      'text-blue': currentPath !== path
    }
  ]
}
    >{title}</a
  >
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `class:list` as mentioned but I think you'll still need [tailwind-merge](https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge/blob/v2.0.0/docs/what-is-it-for.md) so you could use a utility like:

```
import { type ClassValue, clsx } from "clsx";
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge";

export function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]) {
  return twMerge(clsx(inputs));
}

...
// import cn and use 
className={cn(currentPath === path ...)} // etc
```